# Calling MPI Send Again before processor is free

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi

Suppose I've a slave processor working on some problem assigned by master. Now, what happens when I again send a message to that slave processor for some work using MPI_Send?

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
if (masterProcessor) {
     for (;cond1;) {
             MPI_Send(...);
             if (cond2) {
                 MPI_recv(..); // receive from slave
             }
     }
} else {
     MPI_Recv(...); // rec from master
     MPI_Send(...); // send to master 
}
```

What I want to know is if the slave completes and sends before the cond2 in master is true, then what will happen? will the message get lost as there was no receiver for it?

Comment: Do you have some example? If no-one is receiving the send the master will hang at the send.

Answer (score 0):

Provided the first pair Send/Receive is successful the slave will go on ans do the following Send. After that it will wait until the target process does the complementary Receive. The message will not be lost, but the sender will have to wait. If nobody ever receives, it will hang forever.